# Blurry Backdrop for Bootstrap 5 Offcanvas Navbar Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap v5.2 and am trying to replicate the following image.

[Blurry Sidebar Backdrop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdcBx.png)

According to MDN Documention, backdrop-filter is used to blur the background of the element.

```
.offcanvas-backdrop {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px); 
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

But, this didn't work so I tried with the CSS filter:

```
<svg>
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
  </filter>
</svg>

.offcanvas-backdrop{
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
    filter: url($blur);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='10');
}
```

But this also didn't work.

I would appreciate the help from the community.

Answer (score 2):

Apply filter blur when "offcanvas-backdrop" is shown. Set opacity to 1 to override the default opacity 0.5. You may change "background-color" to whatever color you like.

```
.offcanvas-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(15,23,42,.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

Comment: saved my lot of time... i dont know why it has no votes...?? he deserves more